# ArcGIS javascript, convert Graphic to Polygon

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am trying to call [GeometryService.autoComplete](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/geometryservice-amd.html#autocomplete) which has Polygon[] as the first parameter. In my case, I would put the all of the features of my featureLayer. The only property that would seems to work is featureLayer.graphics which contains geometries. But I haven't been able to convert them to Polygon... Is there any way?

Comment: Please describe what you hope to accomplish by calling autoComplete.

Comment: I am tracing a new polygon with the Draw class. Then I want it to be autocompleted if another polygon is underneath. Just like the autocomplete icon in the Editor widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing it manually since I haven't found how to do it...

```
            var polygons = [];
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < featureLayerSelection.graphics.length; i++) {
                polygons[i] = new Polygon(new SpatialReference(featureLayerSelection.graphics[i].geometry.spatialReference.wkid));
                polygons[i].rings = featureLayerSelection.graphics[i].geometry.rings;
                polygons[i].type = featureLayerSelection.graphics[i].geometry.type;
            }
```